# tricky sql interview question(only give you 15mins to solve)

Tags: sql

The given table (order info):

```
client  Date      Product   order amt
1001, 2020-01-01, Desktop1, 100
1001, 2020-01-01, Mobile2,  200
1001, 2020-01-01, Mobile2,  100
1002, 2020-01-02, Mobile1,  100
1002, 2020-01-01, Mobile1,  100
1003, 2020-01-01, Desktop1, 100
1003, 2020-01-02, Desktop2, 100
1004, 2020-01-02, Mobile,   100
```

The return table should give following information:
On each date, how many client buy only one type of product(either mobile_unique or desktop_unique), and the total amount of order under each type of product
AND
On each date, how many client buy both types pf product, and the total amount of order.

So the return table should like this:

```
Date.        product type  total amount  number of client
2020-01-01   mobile_only        100           1
2020-01-01   desktop_only       100           1
2020-01-01   both               400           1
2020-01-02   mobile_only        200           2
2020-01-02   desktop_only       100           1
```

I have solved it by creating multiple tables. But he interviewer only gives 15 mins to solve it, so I'd like to see any simple way to solve it.

Comment: its 29 minutes now. Shall I try?

Answer (score 0):

You can "classify" clients at first (Mob, Des, Bot) and then group:

```
select date_, class, sum(amt), count(client)
  from (
    select date_, client, sum(order_amt) amt,
           case when min(substr(product, 1, 1)) <> max(substr(product, 1, 1)) then 'B'
           else min(substr(product, 1, 1))
           end class
      from orders group by date_, client)
  group by date_, class order by date_, class
```

[dbfiddle for Oracle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3d2a845eae01e3439c38a9f1dc9c0be4)

Answer (score -1):

This seems to be an ill designed table. What if product happens to be a vegetable? I think you should test for sanity of the data a give error in that case.

```
select Date_, product_type, sum(total_amount) as total_amount, count(*) as number_of_clients
from (
    select 
    Date_, sum(order_amt) as total_amount, 
    case 
        when sum(case when SUBSTRING(Product,1,7) = 'Desktop' 
                        or SUBSTRING(Product,1,6) = 'Mobile' 
                      then 0 else 1 end) > 0 then 'Error'
        when count(distinct SUBSTRING(Product,1,6)) = 2 then 'both'
        when min(SUBSTRING(Product,1,6)) = 'Mobile' then 'mobile_only'
        else 'desktop_only'
    end as product_type
    from orders
    group by Date_, client
)x
group by Date_, product_type
order by Date_, product_type desc
```

output:

```
Date_       product_type    total_amount    number_of_clients
2020-01-01  mobile_only     100             1
2020-01-01  desktop_only    100             1
2020-01-01  both            400             1
2020-01-02  mobile_only     200             2
2020-01-02  desktop_only    100             1
```